# Facebook: don't show news from TV shows I "like" in my feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, news-feed

Can I "like" a TV show on Facebook but not see news from it in my News Feed?

I'm not interested in the news and just had an unseen episode spoiled from the show's own news feed item.

I've looked in the Facebook settings but did not find anything obvious to get rid of those feed items.

If nothing else works I'll just remove them from my "likes" entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I "like" a TV show on Facebook but not see news from it in my News Feed?

**Yes**, you can. Click on the **`x`** to the right of any such news item in your feed (it appears when you hover over that item), and choose "**Hide** [page name]".

This way you retain the "like" status (i.e. continue to be a fan, as it used to be called), but you won't get any more updates from them in your feed.

If you ever want to **undo** this for some page, you can do that in your news feed options: scroll down to the bottom of your news feed and click "Edit options" ([Facebook FAQ item on this](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=14574)).

Answer (score 1):

The more recent way to manage this is to go to the page that you "liked" and "unsubscribe" from it. That way you can indicate how you feel about something without reading everything spouted from the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to see news or spoilers about TV shows you like in your newsfeed, one way is to of course unlike the Page of that TV show, or else you could just "unfollow" that Page.

However that will not stop your Facebook friends from writing about the TV show or posting spoilers that will show up in your newsfeed, and facebook does not have a native method for hiding such posts.

One way you can hide such posts is to use a browser add-on such as FB Purity, that lets you filter out newsfeed posts by keyword or phrase. Once you have installed it, just put the names of the TV shows you don't wish to see spoilers or news about into the Text Filter box, which is located on the FB Purity options screen, which you can access by clicking the "FBP" link in the top nav bar at the top of any Facebook page.

You can get **FB Purity** free here: http://www.fbpurity.com